# Dont want to show Id of data in grid

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to display table data on grid but I d'ont want to display table Id.

I also kept **ApplyFormatInEditMode="True"**

If I do datafield **visible= false**. It does not work with edit command.

How to hide Id from Grid.

Here is my code.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="EditExpenses.aspx.cs" Inherits="EditExpenses" %>
```

#### Edit Expenses

```
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Expense_Category" HeaderText="Expense Category" 
            SortExpression="Expense_Category" ApplyFormatInEditMode="True" 
             />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Expense_Description" 
            HeaderText="Expense Description" SortExpression="Expense_Description" 
            ApplyFormatInEditMode="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Expense_Date" HeaderText="Expense Date" 
            SortExpression="Expense_Date" ApplyFormatInEditMode="True" 
            DataFormatString="{0:d}" HtmlEncode="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Amount" HeaderText="Amount" 
            SortExpression="Amount" ApplyFormatInEditMode="True" 
             />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
</div>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testAzharConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT Expense_Category, Expense_Description, Amount, Expense_Date FROM [CompanyExpenses3]"
    UpdateCommand="Update [CompanyExpenses3] SET Expense_Category=@Expense_Category, Expense_Description=@Expense_Description,Expense_Date=@Expense_Date, Amount=@Amount WHERE ExpenseId=@ExpenseId"
          OnUpdated="OnDSUpdatedHandler"></asp:SqlDataSource>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a css class...

```
<style type="text/css">
.hiddencol
    {
        display:none;
    }
    </style>
```

After that in your `Rowcreated`  event of the gridview you can use the `CSS` class..

```
protected void gridview1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {

            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                e.Row.Cells[0].CssClass = "hiddencol";

            }
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
            {
                e.Row.Cells[0].CssClass = "hiddencol";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { }
    }
```

Here `0` is the index of the column you have to hide..

Comment: No, you can write a CSS class as hiddencol and apply it for the particular column which you want to hide onrowcreated event of the Gridview,Regards..

Comment: It's working.. @jameem no question.. once again thanks a lot.